# Handle an event: implement an interface or using inner class to handle the interface. Which is better

Tags: java, android, oop

To handle an event, there are 2 ways:

1. Implementing the callback interface, for example

   ```
   public class A implements View.OnClickListener {
       public void onClick(View v) {
           ....
       }

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           ...
           aboutLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.aboutLayout);
           aboutLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Creating an inner class which implement the callback interface

   ```
   public class ActivityAbout  {
       private class ViewClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
           public void onClick(View v) {
               ..
           }
       }

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           ...
           ViewClickListener listener = new ViewClickListener();
           aboutLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.aboutLayout);
           aboutLayout.setOnClickListener(listener);
       }
   }
   ```

Which one is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use an inner class if either the code is very long (and needs to be organized or methodized), or if I plan to use the same code over and over. Even my `Surface` callbacks are organized as inner classes, just for clarity's sake.

I use an anonymous class if the code is short and easy to handle (perhaps just one line within the event).

I *only ever* use the first implementation if the events are directly related to the class itself, and will never need other listeners attached to it. This is a very rare circumstance. (I also use it for simple debugging, but that's kind of irrelevant here.)

Answer (score 4):

The choice depends entirely the way you plan to use the class, each method is valid and has their corresponding strengths and weaknesses:

- Method 1 is quick to code but limits you to one `onClick()` function, which may or may not become an organizational mess.
- Method 2 allows you to create multiple `onClick()` functions and use them in more logical methods.

But I would like to present Method 3, an anonymous callback:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    OnClickListener myClickListener1 = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ..
        }
    }

    OnClickListener myClickListener2 = new OnClickListener() {...}

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        view.setOnClickListener(myClickListener1);
    }
}
```

Notice that unlike Method 2, I did not create a custom class. I would avoid creating a new custom class unless you are going to add more functionality, keep local variables, or otherwise modify the basic function of an OnClickListener.